# Динамическое обновление данных из сервера django

Tags: javascript, html, django

Хочу передать данные с django на html, но данные передаются только при создании страницы. Как я понял, чтобы добавить динамичности, нужен ajax. Как передать из js в django с помощью ajax уже разобрался, а как передать с django в html/js так, чтобы данные сразу менялись с помощью ajax не знаю.

```
def index(request):
  context = {'str': 'hello world'}
  return render(request, 'liner/editor.html', context)
```

Comment: Никак. Сервер не может прислать Вам данные по `Ajax`, если Вы не отправили на них запрос. Чтобы добиться такой функциональности, посмотрите в сторону `WebSocket` и `django-channels`.

Answer (score 1):

есть 3 способа

- постоянно опрашивать бек на наличие изменений
- WebSocket
- http2 sse

И не важно что у вас там на беке, главное что бы бек соответствующую техналогию поддерживал

Answer (score 1):

Нужно для начало подготовить отдельный url по которому будут эти данный возвращаться в формате json:

views.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def special_data(request):
    data = ...
    return JsonResponse({'data': data})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('json/special_data/', special_data)
]
```

Потом эти данные можно спокойно получать по ссылке в любой момент. Вот к примеру как это сделать с на странице с помощью js jquery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460378/how-to-get-json-from-url-in-javascript

Comment: Данные так доставать? $.getJSON('json/special_data/', function(data) {
    //data is the JSON string
       alert(data);
});

Comment: Выдает ошибку jquery.min.js:2 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/editor/json/special_data/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: " 127.0.0.1:8000/editor/json/special_data" по этой ссылки должна отображаться страница с сырыми данными. Если нет, что-то не так настроил

Comment: как я понимаю, здесь имеются ввиду файлы(urls.py и views.py) из editor?